# What one should reply to - "Can I talk to Jeremy?"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, speech, telephone

> **Situation** I receive a call caller asked me;" Can I talk to Jeremy?"

What is correct reply and What should I respond to this situation with.

> 1. *he has gone for lunch.*
> 2. *he went for lunch.*
> 3. *he is at lunch.*
>
> **Which one should I prefer and why?**

***PS*** *Please also suggest if there is any other better option.*

***Thanks in Advance.***

Comment: Jeremy isn't here.  May I take a message?

Comment: @deadrat what about the options there; can't I use any one of theme?

Comment: @deadrant because may be I don't want to have a headache of passing the message. BTW thanks for reply

Comment: of the ones given I would with 2) He went for lunch, but personally I would use "He has gone **to** lunch"

Comment: @Yeshe Can you please elaborate your choice why would you prefer present-perfect ? In-fact this is the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @user134145 Please edit the question to make it clear what you're asking about, rather than burying that in comments. Tags are fine, but they are essentially for searching and the question really needs to stand without them. [Also, although you have asked for "better suggestions" you don't seem to want one like deadrat's; and they are essentially opinion-based and difficult to vote on.]

Comment: "I assume you can talk, since you're talking now, but you will have difficulty talking to Jeremy since he's not here now."  (The proper inquiry would be "*May* I talk to Jermey?")

Comment: If you won't take Jeremy's messages, he won't take yours.

Comment: thanks for down votes :) and @ab2 lots of love :) and if you had posted you comment as answer; I might have marked that as accepted. :) hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he went somewhere to eat lunch, then he went TO lunch.
If he went somewhere to get lunch and bring it back, then he went FOR lunch. 
But you use the past simple for an action which happend at a definite time in the past (the time is stated, already known or implied).

In this particular situation "he has gone to lunch".
You should use present perfect - this means he has not come back yet, he is still outside.

Answer (score 0):

@Maldin's answer is very nice.  I'll just chime in to answer your question, which one is preferable and why.  I'll warn you though, this is pretty subjective.

> He's at lunch

is good because it rolls off the tongue without having to think about it a lot, and it works in all cases -- he went to a restaurant; he went to the deli for take-out; he's having a salad at his desk and isn't answering the phone, for better digestion and stress relief; he's having a lunch meeting with colleagues; you name it.

Here's a nice situation for the present perfect.  Someone calls for Jeremy.  You say

> Let me check if he's still here.  (Calls over to co-worker)  Has Jeremy left for lunch yet?  (Into phone)  I'm sorry, he's already left for lunch.